# Custom fonts not rendering on heroku in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was able to get fonts working in localhost, but cannot get them working on heroku.

I have been researching and trying things for quite some time and have read several posts but nothing seems to be working.

Here is all relevant information:

**FONT FILE**

I have a font file in 
`/assets/fonts/MavenProLight-300.otf`

**CSS**

In application.css.erb I have

```
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'maven';
        src:font-url('MavenProLight-300.otf');
        src:url('MavenProLight-300.otf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        }
```

**production.rb**

In config/production.rb i have

```
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
  config.assets.enabled = true
```

When i deploy to heroku compile locally

1. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
2. git add public/assets
3. git push heroku master

My guess is this line of code is off:

```
src:font-url('MavenProLight-300.otf');
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`font_url`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/font_url)?

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'maven';
    src: font_url('MavenProLight-300.otf');
    src: font_url('MavenProLight-300.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

Your other steps seem to be correct (at least according to the way we deploy our apps to Heroku)

Comment: I'm using font-URL but then I just have URL - see code above. This was my attempt to have it work in local and heroku. Any other ideas? Thanks for taking the time

Comment: No problem! I saw your code - I have plenty of ideas, but to make better progress, can you show me the code in your compiled CSS which calls that font? I want to see how it's rendering

Comment: I went ahead and tried font_url and that still did not work.  Heroku wrote me back saying my .otf file is available and loaded properly but I'm not using the asset_path helper correctly, so the problem lies therein.  I would expect font_url or font_path or asset_path to work after reading the documentation but none seem to render the font.

Comment: I did not know that it would create the pathing names from the asset path addition. +1

Answer (score 1):

Precompiling or using the production environment only created more errors for me. Here's what worked instead (Rails 6):

1. As described in [this](https://gist.github.com/msyvr/8f1aebf67681ab160e152a995b2ac702) great gist, add the following to `application.rb` (and not anywhere else): `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app","assets","fonts")`
2. Change `src: url('...')` to `font-url('...')` in your scss file
3. `git add -A` and `git commit` the changes
4. `git push` followed by `git push heroku main`*
5. If the application uses a database, `heroku run rails db:migrate`

*If some error about a missing `manifest.json` pops up, run `rails webpacker:install` and start over from step 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing to add to [@RichardPeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143732/richard-peck)'s answer except that remember to use the proper tag to get the ruby to kick in (**.erb file**)

```
@font-face {
       font-family: 'maven';
       src: <%= font_url('MavenProLight-300.otf') %>; // ADD THE TAGS
       src: <%= font_url('MavenProLight-300.otf') %>; // ADD THE TAGS
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
}
```